# Issues regarding Instantiate UI gameobject

Tags: unity-game-engine

I've been tying to instantiate a gameobject prefab which is a button UI type, and change their name so that it has their own identity or so, in my case, i'm trying to change the button name to skill's name

here's my code sample

```
public GameObject buttonObj; //to instantiate
public GameObject buttonParent;
List<GameObject> gameObjects = new List<GameObject>();
public List<Button> skillButtons= new List<Button>();

private void Start()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < skills.Count; i++)
    {
        
        GameObject gotemp = Instantiate(buttonObj);
        gotemp.transform.SetParent(buttonParent.transform,false);
        
        gameObjects.Add(gotemp);

    }
    for (int i = 0; i < skills.Count; i++)
    {
        gameObjects[i].name = skills[i].Name;
        gameObjects[i].GetComponentInChildren<Text>().text = skills[i].Name;
        skillButtons.Add(gameObjects[i].GetComponent<Button>());

    }

}
```

code for skill part

```
 public class Skill  : ScriptableObject
{
    public string Name;
    public int CooldownTurn = 0;
    int cooldownCD;

}
```

by right all buttons should have their different name with it, but it turns out that
[only the 1st one has its name while other doesn't have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T2hlq.png)

i know that i should've merge those 2 loops together since they're under the same loop count, but even i tried that at first, it gives me the same outcome, that's why i try to separate it and see if it works

Comment: You failed to provide details of the `skills List` data structure. What type of values does it hold and what is the content of this List?

Comment: will edit this in main post

Comment: And a screenshot to show the content of the `skills List` please :-) Might be this list has only 1 element with assigned values and the rest have a default empty name field.

Comment: man i've just checked it from my editor script, and turns out that i did not include the 'Name' which supposed to be its string, but included the 'name' instead which only makes the asset name, thanks for the shout out

Comment: Glad it worked for you and remember to always KEEP SMILING :-)

Answer (score 1):

so turns out it's a bug from editor script which is a silly mistakes that i've made
here's the changes that i've made for that
might have to avoid to put a string variable which is near identical to 'name' since it's the name of the gameobject

```
[CustomEditor(typeof(Skill))]

public class SkillEditor : Editor
{
    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {

        Skill selectedSkill = (Skill)target;

        selectedSkill.name = selectedSkill.Name = EditorGUILayout.TextField("Skill Name:", selectedSkill.name);
}
```

Comment: You should put a `serializedObject.Update();` on top of the `OnInspectorGUI` and a `serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();` at the bottom in order to propery handle undo/redo and saving any changed value!

Comment: i'm still new at editor, but thanks for the advise